# Encapsulating with DataflowEx

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

I want to use [DataflowEx](https://github.com/gridsum/DataflowEx) to encapsulate this test. I am not sure that my design is correct as I have tried a lot to do it my self but I failed to make the Dataflow to complete as in my test and is not clear how I should post the server, IP combination from the outside.

```
    class HttpClientHandlerFactory : Dataflow<string, HttpClientHandler> {
        private readonly TransformBlock<string, WebProxy> _webproxyDataflow;
        private readonly TransformBlock<WebProxy, HttpClientHandler> _httpClientHandlerDataflow;

        public HttpClientHandlerFactory(IHttpClientHandlerFactoryData handlerFactoryData) : this(DataflowOptions.Default, handlerFactoryData) {
        }

        public HttpClientHandlerFactory(DataflowOptions dataflowOptions, IHttpClientHandlerFactoryData handlerFactoryData) : base(dataflowOptions){
            var dataflowBlockOptions = dataflowOptions.ToExecutionBlockOption();
            _webproxyDataflow = new TransformBlock<string, WebProxy>(async s => {
                new WebProxy(s);
            }, dataflowBlockOptions);
            _httpClientHandlerDataflow = new TransformBlock<WebProxy, HttpClientHandler>(proxy => new HttpClientHandler(){Proxy = proxy}, dataflowBlockOptions);
            var dataflowLinkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true };
            _webproxyDataflow.LinkTo(_httpClientHandlerDataflow, dataflowLinkOptions, proxy => proxy != null);
            var nullTarget = DataflowBlock.NullTarget<WebProxy>();
            _webproxyDataflow.LinkTo(nullTarget, dataflowLinkOptions, proxy => proxy == null);
            RegisterChild(_webproxyDataflow);
            RegisterChild(_httpClientHandlerDataflow);
        }

        public override ITargetBlock<string> InputBlock => _webproxyDataflow;

        public override ISourceBlock<HttpClientHandler> OutputBlock => _httpClientHandlerDataflow;
    }

    class FactoryData: IHttpClientHandlerFactoryData {


    }
    [Fact]
    public async void MethodName(){
        var httpClientHandlers = new BufferBlock<HttpClientHandler>();
        var httpClientHandlerFactory = new HttpClientHandlerFactory(new FactoryData());
        httpClientHandlerFactory.LinkTo(httpClientHandlers.ToDataflow());
        var baseAddresses = new BufferBlock<Uri>();
        var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<Tuple<HttpClientHandler, Uri>,HttpClient>(
                data => {
                    WriteLine($"{data.Item2.ToString()}-{Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}-{((WebProxy) data.Item1.Proxy).Address}");
                    return new HttpClient(data.Item1){BaseAddress = data.Item2};
                });
        var joinBlock = new JoinBlock<HttpClientHandler,Uri>();
        httpClientHandlers.LinkTo(joinBlock.Target1);
        baseAddresses.LinkTo(joinBlock.Target2);
        joinBlock.LinkTo(transformBlock,new DataflowLinkOptions(){PropagateCompletion = true});

        baseAddresses.Post(new Uri("http://www.serverA.com"));
        baseAddresses.Post(new Uri("http://www.ServerB.com"));
        httpClientHandlerFactory.Post("127.0.0.1");
        httpClientHandlerFactory.Post("127.0.0.2");
        joinBlock.Complete();
        await transformBlock.Completion;

    }
```

**Update**

Reading carefully [JSteward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7339946/jsteward) comment about the missing NullTarget block I realized that my raw block method was incorrect. So here is the correct version.

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task MethodName() {
        var dataflowLinkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true };
        var httpClientHandlerFactory = new HttpClientHandlerFactory(new HttpClientHandlerFactoryData());
        var baseAddresses = new BufferBlock<Uri>();
        var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<Tuple<HttpClientHandler, Uri>, HttpClient>(
                data => {
                    WriteLine($"{data.Item2.ToString()}-{Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}-{((WebProxy)data.Item1.Proxy).Address}");
                    var httpClient = new HttpClient(data.Item1) { BaseAddress = data.Item2 };
                    return httpClient;
                });
        var joinBlock = new JoinBlock<HttpClientHandler, Uri>();
        httpClientHandlerFactory.OutputBlock.LinkTo(joinBlock.Target1,dataflowLinkOptions);
        baseAddresses.LinkTo(joinBlock.Target2,dataflowLinkOptions);
        joinBlock.LinkTo(transformBlock, dataflowLinkOptions);


        baseAddresses.Post(new Uri("http://www.serverA.com"));
        baseAddresses.Post(new Uri("http://www.ServerB.com"));
        httpClientHandlerFactory.Post("127.0.0.1");
        httpClientHandlerFactory.Post("127.0.0.2");

        httpClientHandlerFactory.Complete();
        baseAddresses.Complete();
        transformBlock.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<HttpClient>(), dataflowLinkOptions);

        await transformBlock.Completion;

    }
```

It completes with this output.

> 02:51:41.3365|http://www.servera.com/-11-http://127.0.0.1/
>     02:51:41.3365|http://www.serverb.com/-11-http://127.0.0.2/

Now to migrate to DataflowEx I declared the next class

```
    class HttpClientFactory:Dataflow<string,HttpClient>{
        private readonly HttpClientHandlerFactory _httpClientHandlerFactory;
        private readonly TransformBlock<Tuple<HttpClientHandler, Uri>, HttpClient> _transformBlock;
        private JoinBlock<HttpClientHandler, Uri> _joinBlock;
        private BufferBlock<Uri> _baseAddresses;

        public HttpClientFactory(IHttpClientFactoryData httpClientHandlerFactoryData) : this(DataflowOptions.Default, httpClientHandlerFactoryData) {
        }

        public HttpClientFactory(DataflowOptions dataflowOptions, IHttpClientFactoryData handlerFactoryData) : base(dataflowOptions) {
            var dataflowLinkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true };
            _httpClientHandlerFactory = new HttpClientHandlerFactory(new HttpClientHandlerFactoryData());

            _baseAddresses = new BufferBlock<Uri>();
            _transformBlock = new TransformBlock<Tuple<HttpClientHandler, Uri>, HttpClient>(
                data => {
                    handlerFactoryData.Logger.WriteLine($"{data.Item2.ToString()}-{Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}-{((WebProxy)data.Item1.Proxy).Address}");
                    return new HttpClient(data.Item1) { BaseAddress = data.Item2 };
                });
            _joinBlock = new JoinBlock<HttpClientHandler, Uri>();

            _httpClientHandlerFactory.OutputBlock.LinkTo(_joinBlock.Target1,dataflowLinkOptions);
            _baseAddresses.LinkTo(_joinBlock.Target2,dataflowLinkOptions);
            _joinBlock.LinkTo(_transformBlock, dataflowLinkOptions);
            RegisterChild(_transformBlock);
            RegisterChild(_httpClientHandlerFactory);
            RegisterChild(_baseAddresses);
            foreach (var baseAddress in handlerFactoryData.BaseAddresses){
                _baseAddresses.Post(baseAddress);
            }
        }

        public override ITargetBlock<string> InputBlock => _httpClientHandlerFactory.InputBlock;

        public override ISourceBlock<HttpClient> OutputBlock => _transformBlock;
    }
```

and wrote a test that it completes ok with the expected output

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task MethodName2(){
        var clientFactoryData = new HttpClientFactoryData(new[]{new Uri("http://www.serverA.com")}){Logger = this};
        var httpClientFactory = new HttpClientFactory(DataflowOptions.Verbose,clientFactoryData);
        httpClientFactory.InputBlock.Post("127.0.0.1");
        httpClientFactory.LinkLeftToNull();
        httpClientFactory.Complete();

        await httpClientFactory.OutputBlock.Completion;
    }
```

> 02:55:44.8536|[HttpClientFactory1] has 0 todo items (in:0, out:0) at this moment.
>     02:55:45.0039|[HttpClientFactory1]->[HttpClientHandlerFactory1] completed
>     02:55:45.0039|http://www.servera.com/-11-http://127.0.0.1/

However in in the above test I used the raw Complete method and awaited on the OutputBlock and not on the DataFlow. The next test that uses the builtin Dataflow method does not complete.

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task MethodName2(){
        var clientFactoryData = new HttpClientFactoryData(new[]{new Uri("http://www.serverA.com")}){Logger = this};
        var httpClientFactory = new HttpClientFactory(DataflowOptions.Verbose,clientFactoryData);
        httpClientFactory.InputBlock.Post("127.0.0.1");
        httpClientFactory.LinkLeftToNull();


        await httpClientFactory.SignalAndWaitForCompletionAsync();
    }
```

Comment: The test will not finish since the last block will collect all items in its output buffer. You need to link the `TransformBlock` to a `NullTarget` lIke you did in the DataflowEx flow. [See here for another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455192/tpl-dataflow-never-completes-when-using-a-predicate). Are you also having an issue with the DataflowEx side?

Comment: hmm maybe i was not clear enough, the test i posted which uses raw blocks works fine and finishes ok. But my problem is how to migrate to DataflowEx

Comment: My tests uses mixed raw and DataflowEx blocks, so I want to migrate them and encapsulated them all in one DataflowEx class

Comment: Ok, It should be straight forward, just building the pipeline and registering the blocks but maybe I'm not quite understanding what your asking. Can you elaborate on what exactly isn't working with the DataflowEx implementation?

Comment: With regard to your test, How are you verifying the test completes? As posted it's an `async void` so xUnit is not going to wait for `Completion`. The test should be an `async Task`.

Comment: I will update a simplified version of my DataflowEx attempt. I tested your async Task suggestion but still completes fine, I have also used the Completion.Wait(); and still completes fines

Comment: FYI - if your looking to have a DataflowEx `Dataflow` based off a `JoinBlock` unfortunately that's not supported. **[See here](https://github.com/gridsum/DataflowEx/issues/4)**. The complication is only when the `JoinBlock` is the first in your flow since it has two targets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162626/discussion-between-apostolis-bekiaris-and-jsteward).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the Complete method to complete the additional BufferBlock makes the test pass.

```
public override void Complete(){
    base.Complete();
    _baseAddresses.Complete();
}
```